# How to update one entry in local storage on keypress vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I have a to-do-list app that stores and retrieves data from local storage. I am working on the edit functionality and I am wondering how do I update the task in local storage after I press enter.

Currently, this is how I have implemented it

[image]

```
const editTask = (event) => {
  const task = event.target;
  if (task.className === 'edit-button') {
    const { previousSibling } = task;
    const makeEdit = previousSibling.previousSibling;

    makeEdit.removeAttribute('readonly');
    makeEdit.focus();
    makeEdit.classList.toggle('focus');

    makeEdit.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        makeEdit.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
        makeEdit.classList.toggle('focus');

        const storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('task-list'));
        const tasks = [...document.querySelectorAll('.task-item')];

        storage.forEach((element, i) => {
          element.description = tasks[i].value;
        });
        localStorage.setItem('task-list', JSON.stringify(storage));
      }
    });
  }
};
```

When the enter key is pressed I am updating all tasks in local storage with the input values (which doesn't seem efficient) . How can I target just that one task from local storage and update its value on pressing enter?

Comment: if you just want the one - create separate keys, but that would be hard to maintain

Comment: Instead of `task.className === 'edit-button'`, _please_ use [`task.classList.contains("edit-button")`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).